# Looking for easy to use free image data annotation tool online

Tags: web-apps, image-processing, data-analysis

I am looking for an easy to use free image data annotation tool online for computer vision-related task (deep learning). Any kind of suggestion would be really great.

Background: I will use at most 1000 image for the annotation purpose. So, if there is any free to use annotation tool online which serves less than 1000 images data to annotate in their free version please let me know that as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "image data"? Do you e.g. plan to upload JPG files and have the annotation in their Exif data then? // PS: as "best" is always subjective (without criteria given), I've removed that term. Hope you didn't have the impression we'd otherwise only recommend the worst here? ;)

Comment: .... or do you want to  assign labels to images and classify them into  predefined categories, recognize objects and faces and the like?